# Stop ComboBox from scrolling to top

Tags: c#, wpf

In `WPF`, is there any way to disable the scroll behavior of the `ComboBox` that auto-scrolls to the top of the list whenever a user reaches the end of the list? I'd rather that the list stayed at the end and the user have to manually scroll back to the top.

Heres the XAML for the `ComboBox`:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="CellProviderCombo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="65" Margin="14,405,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width=" 327" Header="Cell Provider" PlaceholderText="Choose Cell Provider" DataContext="{StaticResource GlobalVars}" ItemsSource="{Binding GlobalShopInfo.CellProviders}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"/>
```

As I said, if you scroll past the last element in the combobox it simply starts over at the bottom and the scroll bar shoots back up to the top automatically.

Comment: perhaps this posting may help you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a3532b1f-d76e-4955-b3da-84c98d6d435c/annoying-auto-scroll-of-partially-displayed-items-in-wpf-listbox?forum=wpf

Comment: Please post code.  It does not work that way for me.

Comment: @MethodMan Yea I saw that but because I am using a binding to determine the contents of the ComboBox, I don't have a ListBox.ItemContainerStyle to modify.

Comment: @Blam added code to main post

Comment: I don't have that problem with CombBox.  I suggest you post a full sample to reproduce the problem.    And don't clutter sample code with Height, Margin ... that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: This is from the Windows.UI.Xaml?  That is a very important detail to include.

Comment: I added my own answer, the issue was that the combobox in WPF is not the same as the combobox in Windows Apps. I had to manually change the template to get it to behave.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that the `ComboBox` in WPF is not the same `ComboBox` used in Windows Apps `Windows.UI.Xaml`.

The `ComboBox` used in Windows Apps uses a `Carousel` instead of a `StackPanel` to display its items. One of the effects this has is making it so when you reach the end of the list, it simply loops back to the top. The solution is to manually change the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to a `StackPanel` as follows:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"> //Add other properties in this line as well if needed
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Hope this helps anyone who has a similar issue.

Comment: I have strange issue when using this solution: first item is always stays highlighted and it can't be selected. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Borzh: same here (among other strange side effects) - have you found a solution for that?

Comment: @PrinceCharles It's been a long time, but I remember that I didn't use this solution.

Comment: I used this style, not sure if this will help: 
    <Style x:Key="BaseComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>

Comment: ok, thank you @Borzh! the style you gave does nothing in the direction of the actual problem, so i doubt this will solve anything - but thanks for looking!